# Can we change content of a class on different size classes

Tags: ios, class, size

I have a UITableView on 'wCompact hRegular' and I have 2 views in that tableView.
Now when I change the device orientation to 'wAny hCompact',I want to have one view outside the tableView and the other view should remain inside the tableView.

I have just learned to use size classes and I am not sure if this is possible or not.I am not able to do this on my storyboard.If yes, how?

[image]
This is the landscape view where I have yellow view outside UITableView .I want this yellow view inside tableView in portrait.Is this possible or do I need to design another view?

Comment: It's possible, if you are using xcode 8, just enter vary for trait and start delete/add contraint or any other view in, it will change for only that kind of size

Comment: ok I will try .

Comment: I can't change the parents .....The rest is working as expected.But I don't think we can change the parent